# How to revoke or delete firebase Dynamic link programmatically?

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links

I have successfully create a firebase dynamic link programmatically, but I see no docs on how to actually revoke that dynamic link.
Assume the following scenario, in a messaging app like what's app there is a group, the group admin sends out a deep link to subscribe more members to his group. Somehow, his dynamic link ends up in bad hands and lots of unwanted people join the group. How can he revoke the link to avoid others from joining in the group?

Comment: The question is a little unclear. A dynamic link can be used to, for example, have a user click on a link on a web page and then be directed to the app store to download the app. Or create a link between two existing users. Either way, the user still must authenticate with their existing account or create a new account (assuming that functionality is implemented). You control that authentication process and can deny access to an unauthenticated user.

Comment: @Jay I understand. It makes sense. One more question. I have created a UserModel which stores in FirebaseDdatabase: zipCode, latitude and longitude. In the UI a user can enter a zip and then I need to look up firebase database for the users which are in a radius of 10 km. I can see that there is a library `github.com/firebase/geofire-objc`, but there are no commits since May. Is this the appropriate library to use or what should I use for my use case? many thanks

Comment: The comments section here is really reserved for comments to the original question. A different question should be posted a separate question so it can added the the community of questions so it can help others. Be sure it's not a duplicate - in this case there's lot of existing questions (and answers!) about Geofire, it's use and implementation.

Comment: I am apologize, I will do as you advised.