# Why .childAdded is not called when new data is added? Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read data from `media` when data is updated on /media node, but `.observe(.childAdded` is not called.
 For example, I update data at `/media/-LKN1j_FLQuOvnhEFfao/caption` , but I never receive the event in observeNewMedia .
 I can read the data with no problem the first time when `ViewDidLoad` completes.

The first step is to download the user data, second is to get the *locality* from currentUser and the last step is to attach a listener `.childAdded` on media.
I suspect that the event is not triggered because `fetchMedia` is called inside `DDatabaseRReference.users(uid: uid).reference().observe(.value`

```
media
  -LKNRdP4ZsE3YrgaLB30
        caption: "santa"
        mediaUID: "-LKNRdP4ZsE3YrgaLB30"
        locality: "barking"

users
  Q6Dm3IMLNLgBH3ny3rv2CMYf47p1
       media
          -LKNReJCxgwtGRU6iJmV: "-LKNRdP4ZsE3YrgaLB30"
       email: "john@gmail.com"
       locality: "barking"


  //enables the programmer to create references to different childs in Firebase
  enum DDatabaseRReference {

   case root
   case users(uid:String)
   case media  //to store photos

    func reference() -> DatabaseReference {
       return rootRef.child(path)
   }


  //return root reference to our database
   private var rootRef: DatabaseReference {
       return Database.database().reference()
  }

private var path: String {

      switch self { //self is the enum DDatabaseReference
       case .root:
         return ""

       case .users(let uid):
         return "users/\(uid)"

       case .media:
          return "media"        
       }
    }

  }//end of enum DatabaseReference




 class NewsfeedTableViewController: UITableViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

            //observe ~/users/uid
    DDatabaseRReference.users(uid: uid).reference().observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
                self.currentUser = UserModel(dictionary: userDict)
                self.fetchMedia()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })

  }

    func fetchMedia() {   

 Media.observeNewMedia((currentUser?.locality)!) { (newMedia) in

        //check if newly downloaded media is already in media array
        if !self.media.contains(newMedia) {
            self.media.insert(newMedia, at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }else {
            //remove old media and add the newly updated one
            guard let index = self.media.index(of: newMedia) else {return}
            self.media.remove(at: index)
            self.media.insert(newMedia, at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

 }//end of NewsfeedTableViewController


 class Media {

class func observeNewMedia(_ userLocality: String, _ completion: @escaping (Media) -> Void) {


    DDatabaseRReference.media.reference().queryOrdered(byChild: "locality").queryEqual(toValue: userLocality).observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        guard snapshot.exists() else {
       print("no snap ")
        return}
        print("snap is \(snapshot)")
        let media = Media(dictionary: snapshot.value as! [String : Any])
        completion(media)
    })
  }
} //end of class Media
```

Comment: You're observing a node by child "locality" which doesn't appear to exist in the Firebase structure included in the question. It's not clear which node is actually being observed / queried though. The question says you are trying to observe the media node but you've added a query to 'filter' the results, not just an observer. Also, you're using *media.reference()* but it's not clear why.

Comment: @Jay I've created an enum `DDatabaseRReference` to create references to firebase easier. In viewDidLoad  `users/userUID` is observed. Once a UserModel is initialized and I have the value of `locality` property,  a query is made on `media/mediaUID` and in the same time a `childAdded` event is appended to the firebase reference. What I want is to get updates from firebase every time a child or its descendant children are added or modified  at `/media/mediaUID` . In other words, if `media/-LKNRdP4ZsE3YrgaLB30/caption` receives a new value, I'd like to receive that data.

Comment: mediaUID doesn't have a child like that in the Firebase structure. It's showing *mediaUID: "-LKNRdP4ZsE3YrgaLB30"* so it's child is a string of *-LKNRdP4ZsE3YrgaLB30*. I think you may want to .observe with .childAdded to media node to get events when children are added to that node. Also, there's not reason to store a child node that has the same value as the parent node as the parentNode is the key, which is always available from snapshot.key.

Comment: There's quite a bit of code in the question so it's unclear what you're trying to do. Here's a guess - let me know if this is accurate; for the currently logged in user, you want to receive events when new media is added, changed or removed from the media node? Those changes should then be reflected in the self.media array so the UI can be updated accordingly

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. For the currently logged in user, I want to receive events when new media is added, changed or removed at : media/mediaUID .  mediaUID is the value  by which I identify each media object. You can see that this value appears once in /users LKNRdP4ZsE3YrgaLB30 and then again in /media .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first update the structure so make it more queryable

assume a users node

```
users
   -Q6Dm3IMLNLgBH3ny3rv2CMYf47p1  //this is each users uid
      email: "john@gmail.com"
      locality: "barking"
```

and a media node that contains media for all users

```
media
   -abcdefg12345 //node created with childByAutoId
      caption: "santa"
      for_uid: -Q6Dm3IMLNLgBH3ny3rv2CMYf47p1 //matches the uid in the /users node
```

Then our main viewController which contains a reference to Firebase and logs the user in

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var ref: DatabaseReference!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.ref = Database.database().reference()
      //log user in which will populate the Auth.auth.currentUser variable
    }
   .
   .
   .
```

We need an object to store the media in and then an array to hold those objects

```
class MediaClass {
    var key = ""
    var caption = ""

    init(k: String, c: String) {
        self.key = k
        self.caption = c
    }
}

var mediaArray = [MediaClass]()
```

then set up the observers which will add, update or remove from the array when media for this user is added, changed or removed.

```
let thisUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
let mediaRef = self.ref.child("media")

let queryRef = mediaRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "for_uid").queryEqual(toValue: thisUid)

queryRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
    let dict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
    let key = snapshot.key
    let caption = dict["caption"] as! String
    let m = MediaClass.init(k: key, c: caption)
    self.mediaArray.append(m)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})

queryRef.observe(.childChanged, with: { snapshot in
    let dict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
    let key = snapshot.key
    let caption = dict["caption"] as! String
    let index = self.mediaArray.index { $0.key == key } //locate this object in the array
    self.mediaArray[index!].caption = caption //and update it's caption
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})

//leaving this an an exercise
queryRef.observe(.childRemoved....
```

Note we added .childAdded, .childChanged and .childRemoved events to the media node via a query so the only events the app will receive are the ones that pertain to this user.

Also note there's no error checking so that needs to be added.

Comment: Both `MediaClass` and `UserModel` have a property named: locality. I want to get FirDataEvent only when user.locality == media.locality . In order to do that, first step is to 1. download the the user child (when I login I get only the `uid`), 2. get the locality of user and 3. create the query which would look like: `let queryRef = mediaRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "for_uid").queryEqual(toValue: locality)`. Should I create a computed property which when it is set, it will call `queryRef.observe(childAdded,` and `queryRef.observe(.childChanged` ? Is this the right approach?

Comment: @bibscy So you want to get events for the user only when the media.locality equals the locality of what's in that users locality node? Can you elaborate a bit on that? When would there be a media node for that user that wouldn't also match the locality?

Comment: That is exactly what I want and in order to achieve that I created a computed property with a setter, named currentUser. When this property is set, then I attach `queryRef.observe(childAdded` and  `queryRef.observe(.childChanged` Is this the right approach? It seems to be working.

Comment: I am glad it's working and that may mean it's the correct approach. Let us know if you run into other issues.

Comment: I asked a question a while ago about deleting/revoking a dynamic firebase link programmtically , however, I couldn't get an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860802 . Many thanks for your continuous help :)